# Drupal View Show Webforms NOT Submitted By Logged In User

Tags: users, webforms, views

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this because I have been stuck on this for days...

I have a bunch of webforms that each user needs to submit. I figured out how to show a view of the webforms the logged in user has submitted, but what I am stuck on is showing the webforms the user has NOT submitted in a view. So it would be a list of the webforms the user still needs to fill out.

There must be something small I am overlooking. I appreciate any ideas or help, thanks!

Comment: Just wondering if you had come up with a solution as we are struggling with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about this question: but here you go. Go to View and to ADVANCED>RELATIONSHIP> SElect USer. After that FILTER CRITERIA and add USER as well. NEXT, create roles and work around roles and users.